# Drag and drop attachments from Outlook on Windows to Chrome Browser no longer available

Tags: google-chrome, email, microsoft-outlook, browser

I used to be able to upload documents onto Sharepoint by dragging from the email on Outlook to Chrome.

Recently, a greyed-out disabled mouse shows up on Chrome when I try to drop it.

My work revolves around data storage for documentation and now I have to save the attachments to my downloads folder, and then upload them to Chrome. After uploading, I have to delete the file from my hard drive. A simple 2 step process is now 5 steps, that does not include the data checking and file naming steps.

Is there a new update or a fix to rectify this?

Outlook on Windows (Build 14326.21286) to Chrome Browser (Version 107.0.5304.122)

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Do you have the same issue with Edge or Firefox?

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem with Edge (Ver 107.0.1418.26) too. Not so sure about Firefox as I don't use that browser for work. I use Chrome for work more often.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done any specific operations before that?

Based on my test on Chrome (version 110.0.5481.100) and Outlook 365 (version 2301(Build 16026.20200 Click-to-Run)), i can directly drag and drop the email attachments from Outlook 365 to SharePoint Documents on Chrome. Please **update** Chrome and Outlook desktop client to the latest version and check if the issue persists.

Comment: This is a work computer and updates are only allowed through them. This action was available for me prior to Jan 2023 and I've spoken to Helpdesk but they don't seem to know what's wrong either.

Comment: What about changing to another Browser to use Sharepoint?